# minted+latex: color differently every occurrence of a given command

Tags: minted

Say my LaTeX package defines only `\MyMarvelousCommand`.
In my package documentation, I have many different listings typeset with minted. `\MyMarvelousCommand` should appear in red inside each listing.

Here is my actual solution:

1. use minted's `escapeinside||`
2. In all my listings, replace `\MyMarvelousCommand` by `|\MyMarvelousCommand|`
3. Redefine `\MyMarvelousCommand` at the beginning of the minted environment using hooks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{minted}
\newcommand\MyMarvelousCommand[1]{Do marvelous things with #1}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{
  \def\MyMarvelousCommand{{\color{red}\string\MyMarvelousCommand}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{latex}
\texttt{|\MyMarvelousCommand|{\LaTeX}}
\end{minted}
\texttt{\MyMarvelousCommand{\LaTeX}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is far from optimal:

1. I must parse the code by myself
2. It breaks MWE with spurious characters, which is *very* annoying
3. it does not work on listing+output examples (like in tcblisting)

Is there another approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I add two options to `minted`

- `post processor=<script.py>`
- `post processor args=<more_args>`

`minted` is also patched to execute `python3 <script.py> <hash.pygtex> <more_arg>` before input a `<hash.pygtex>` file each time. Here `<hash.pygtex>` represents the (intermediate) output tex file of `pygments`. You can think it as the cached `_mint-<main>/<hash.pygtex>`.

Then your need can be served by a simple python script which replaces `\MyMarvelousCommand` to a wrapped form, like `\wrapper{\MyMarvelousCommand}`. Since we are handling the `pygments` output, `\<cmd>` is actually `\PYGZbs{}<cmd>`.

Since `pygments` is itself a python library, executing a python script will not add any extra dependencies. Also the following script is more or less a proof-of-concept, so you can extend the script to make it more flexible.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import fileinput
import sys

# This is `highlightcmd.py`
# Usage: python3 highlightcmd.py xxx.pygtex MyCommandFirst

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    raise ValueError(f'Need three args, given {len(sys.argv)}')

fin = sys.argv[1]
cmd = sys.argv[2]
wrapper = sys.argv[3]
# python highlighter of vscode accepts only uppercase `R` to represent raw string
# see https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/issues/114
pattern_find = fR'{{\PYGZbs{{}}{cmd}}}'
pattern_sub = fR'{{\{wrapper}{{\PYGZbs{{}}{cmd}}}}}'

with fileinput.input(fin, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(pattern_find, pattern_sub), end='')
```

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand\MyMarvelousCommand[1]{Do marvelous things with #1}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\minted@inputpyg{%
  \minted@postprocesspyg
    {\minted@get@opt{post processor}{}}
    {\minted@outputdir\minted@infile}
    {\minted@get@opt{post processor args}{}}%
}{}{\fail}

\minted@def@opt{post processor}
\minted@def@opt{post processor args}

% #1 = name of the python script, e.g., "process.py"
% #2 = input ".pygtex" file, always be "\minted@outputdir\minted@infile"
% #3 = more args passed to the python script, possibly empty
\newcommand{\minted@postprocesspyg}[3]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{}{%
    % execute "python3 <script.py> <file.pygtex> <more_args>"
    \ShellEscape{python3 #1 #2 #3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setminted{
  autogobble,
  post processor=highlightcmd.py,
  post processor args=MyMarvelousCommand wrapper
}
\newcommand{\wrapper}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{minted}{latex}
  \MyMarvelousCommand{\LaTeX}
\end{minted}
\texttt{\MyMarvelousCommand{\LaTeX}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works as is on OSX. I reverted the order of arguments #2 and #3 such that I could add `\MySecondCommand`, \MyThirdCommand` as arguments #4, #5, ... to the process.

Comment: You can make `#3` accept a list of csnames, like `"MySecondCommand, MyThirdCommand, ..."`. Parsing a list is much easier in python than in tex.  For a more flexible example, `python3 highlightcmd.py xxx.pygtex --red "cmd1, cmd2" --blue "cmd3,cmd4"`.

Comment: As I do not need such flexibility, I just replaced python assignment `cmd=sys.arg[2]` by `for cmd in sys.argv[3:]:` and indent next instructions appropriately.